# How to create a page without a menu

Tags: wordpress

I tried to create new page template to remove `get_header()` from the template.
But, `get_header()` paste not only `menu` but also other head elements (scripts, styles and etc.)

May be exists another way instead of a page template?

Please answer without plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can simple create a new page on Wordpress backend e.g demo

2) Then create a new template file in theme with name `page-demo.php` .

3) After then its upto you to use `get_header()` on this template file or just explicitly include the scripts/ styles that you want.

### **File formats :**

**With get_header()**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="content"></div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**Without get_header()**

```
<script src=""></script>           
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" /> \\ script and styles to be used only for this page
<div id="content"></div>
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

add condition on menu in header.php

```
if (!is_page_template('page_template_name.php')):
    wp_nav_menu(your array);
endif;
```